# Showing that trajectories deviate from straight line in accelerated reference frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames

**Explanation of light bending in an accelerated frame in a relativistic setting**

We know the transformation that takes us from one inertial frame to another. In special relativity, the transformation is a Lorentz transformation. For example, in an inertial frame K' that moves uniformly with velocity $V$ along the positive x-axis, relative to an inertial frame K, the transformation reads:
$$t'=\gamma(t-Vx/c^2), x'=\gamma(x-Vt),y'=y, z'=z$$
where $\gamma=\sqrt{1-V^2/c^2}$. This transformation maps a light trajectory $x=ct$ in K frame to $x'=ct'$ in the K' frame i.e. under Lorentz transformation light trajectories in spacetime do not bend.

Now consider the case where $K'$ is a non-inertial frame. To be specific, let the K' frame moves away from the inertial frame K along the x-axis with a uniform acceleration $A$. Can we write the transformation properties between K and K' in this scenario and using that, argue that the light trajectory in spacetime no longer remains a straight line in an accelerated frame?

**Susskind's explanation of light bending in an accelerated frame in a nonrelativistic setting**

In Susskind's General Relativity course (See [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRZgW1YjCKk)), he imagines a situation where an elevator moves vertically up with a uniform acceleration $g$. If an observer in the elevator shoots a laser in a horizontal direction, she will find that the laser beam is deflected downwards. This is because the elevator accelerates up. But to me, this explanation is not satisfactory or maybe I am not sure what is meant here. Why? In the non-relativistic setting, the downward deflection of the laser will also occur, if the elevator moves vertically up with a uniform velocity (instead of a uniform acceleration). In the accelerated case, the trajectory will be *curved*. But, in the uniformly moving case, it will of course, deflect but remain *linear*. Is this what he meant?

Answer (score 2):

The Lorentz transformation are only applicable to observers with constant velocity. The observer's do not experience proper acceleration so they are not equivalent to an observer that is stationary with respect to a gravitational field. Instead of using the Lorentz transformation use [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates), which is the point of view of a set of observers that are accelerating in flat spacetime.

> If an observer in the elevator shoots a laser in a horizontal
> direction, she will find that the laser beam is deflected downwards.
> This is because the elevator accelerates up. But to me, this
> explanation is not satisfactory or maybe I am not sure what is meant
> here.

This accelerating observer experiences proper acceleration and this is what makes the elevator observer equivalent to an accelerated observer in a gravitational field and you agree that they would see the light ray curve.

In the second example you give with the observer in an elevator that has constant upward velocity, the observer does not experience proper acceleration, so she is an inertial observer and clearly not equivalent to an accelerated observer that is stationary with respect to a gravitational field. As you have already noted, this inertial observer sees the light ray travel in a straight line, but at a different angle to that observed by other inertial observers with different relative velocities.

> Can you write the transformation from the coordinates of an inertial
> observer to the coordinates of a Rindler observer?

Yes, the transformations are there in the linked Wikipedia article.

If T, X, Y and Z are the coordinates according to the inertial observer, then the coordinates (t, x, y and z) according to a given accelerating Rindler observer with constant proper acceleration $a = 1/X$ are:

$$t = \frac 1a \ arctanh^{-1} \left(\frac TX \right), \ x = \sqrt{X^2-T^2}, \ y = Y, \ z = Z.$$

To see how a straight light ray appears curved to the accelerating observer, consider a light ray that is travelling with a constant X coordinate and a Y coordinate that is increasing with time so Y = T.

The transformed coordinates of this light ray are:

$$x  = \sqrt{X^2-T^2}, \ t = \frac1a \ arctanh\left(\frac xT \right),$$
which looks essentially the same as the worldline of an inertial observer that is at rest in the Minkowski coordinate system as seen by the accelerating observer.

Plotting the above coordinates as a parametric equation with T as the parameter gives the blue curve in the chart below.

[image]

This is how the light ray appears to 'fall' in a curved path from the point of view of the accelerated observer and can be seen to asymptotically approach the Rindler event horizon at $X =0$

The red curves are 'downward' and 'upward' light rays defining a light cone and the 'downward' light ray also asymptotically approaches the event horizon from the accelerating observer's point of view.

The parametric equations for the light cone are
$$x  = \sqrt{(X_h-T)^2-T^2}, \ t = \frac1a \ arctanh\left(\frac {T}{X_h-T} \right)$$

and

$$x  = \sqrt{(X_H+T)^2-T^2}, \ t = \frac1a \ arctanh\left(\frac {T}{X_h+T} \right),$$

where $X_h$ is the 'height' ($ X_h = 10$ in this example) of the accelerating observer at time $T = 0$ and constant proper acceleration $a = \frac{1}{X_h}$.

Comment: Can you write the transformation from the coordinates of an inertial observer to the coordinates of a Rindler observer?

Comment: @Solidification Added your requested transformation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, in [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) accelerated frames are not the same as inertial frames and (unfortunately) there isn't a straightforward transformation like that of the [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) for their connection.

The trajectory of a photon in a gravitational field or accelerated frame yields an offset from the straight line in spacetime. This in particular is one of the main points in the equivalence principle in general relativity. Furthermore, in terms of light, it follows what is known as a "[geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)" in spacetime, which is the course that minimizes the proper time (or equivalently, maximizes the coordinate time, it's the same thing).

To sum it up, the frame of the accelerated process will not have a simple mathematical transformation such as the Lorentz transformation to the inertial frame, since the interaction with gravitational effects and acceleration depends on more detailed considerations.

Comment: How do you demonstrate that light deviates from the straight path in an accelerated frame? We can invoke the equivalence principle to argue that gravity bends light, too.

Comment: To demonstrate that light deviates from a straight path in an accelerated frame, you can use the equivalence principle, which states that the effects of gravity are locally indistinguishable from the effects of acceleration. This principle allows us to draw parallels between the behavior of light in an accelerated frame and in a gravitational field. If you want a more detailed explanation we could start a chatroom

Comment: I want to do the reverse. I want to show that light deviates from a straight path in an accelerated frame and then invoke the equivalence principle to show that the same must happen in a gravitational field. This is how Susskind argues why light should bend in a gravitational field (see the linked video).

Answer (score 0):

I have only gotten through the first 20 minutes because it is all I have time for right now but it is an excellent lecture.

In the beginning of it, Professor Suskind assumes that light is traveling infinitely fast, while using Galilean transformations (non relativistic, not special relativity), for illustrative purposes. In that example, light can’t be deflected, because it travels from one side of the elevator to the other instantaneously.

Moving on to special relativity, which I didn’t watch. In that case, the Lorentz transformations themselves can be proved by the requirement that the light should not be deflected in either the moving nor the stationary frame at constant velocity.

Moving on to general relativity. If special relativity is already assumed so that at constant velocity light moving along X is undeflected, then in an accelerated elevator, light is deflected. Gravitational acceleration is equivalent to net acceleration and space is locally flat ignoring tidal forces.

Unfortunately I am very very rusty on GR. I remember that gravitational acceleration in some way relates to the Lie derivative of the metric (which I guess is analogous to saying the gravitational force is a derivative of a potential, where the “potential”, that isn’t really a potential, is spacetime) and acceleration is its usual self but a tensor. Another way to think of it is to use Lagrangians. From that, the geodesic equation. But I’m missing a few steps.

In particular, this neglects the conceptual cases of a rotating elevator or an elevator being held up by a force that is not gravity.

Comment: Can you specifically address the doubt/question I am raising in the last paragraph of my post?

Comment: "Why? In the non-relativistic setting, the downward deflection of the laser will also occur, if the elevator moves vertically up with a uniform velocity (instead of a uniform acceleration). In the accelerated case, the trajectory will be curved. But, in the uniformly moving case, it will of course, deflect but remain linear. Is this what he meant?"   I do believe I did. If an elevator is moving at constant velocity, special relativity governs it, and within any given non-rotating reference frame, light travels in a straight path. I'm honestly confused, not trying to dodge the question.

Comment: Do you mean constant velocity driven by a force in a gravitational field? I don't actually think it is possible to move at constant velocity (maybe it is at constant speed but not constant velocity) in a curved spacetime/gravitational field unless some force like a rocket is applied. Well unless it's weird so the gradient is exactly zero.

Comment: In the first 20 minutes of the video, which is nearly 2 hours (if I recall), Professor Susskind derives some principles about Galilean transformations and elevators in the context of gravity. In particular, he finds that F-mg = ma (if I recall what he means).  I'm not sure specifically what he says about Galilean light deflection, but he did say that he assumed light travelled at infinite speed, so in principle he probably meant it was undeflected while assuming Galilean transformations (classical, not special or general relativity)? I did not see the rest of the lecture though.